# Angular Template is displaying "data is [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]"

Tags: angular

Here is the sample JsonObject I am trying to get:

```
{"statusType":"OK","entity":
  {"mainprop":
   [{"fields":{
      "prop1":[value1],
      "prop2":[value2],
      "prop3":[value3]
   }}],
   [{"fields":{
      "prop1":[value1],
      "prop2":[value2],
      "prop3":[value3]
   }}],
   [{"fields":{
      "prop1":[value1],
      "prop2":[value2],
      "prop3":[value3]
   }}]
  }
}
```

Here is my SomeComponentInterface for binding the json object:

```
export interface SomeComponentInterface {
 fields:{
          prop1:string[],
          prop2:string[],
          prop3:string[]
}
```

Here is my code in TS Service (annotated with @Injectable()):

```
 getDocumentService(): Observable<SomeComponentInterface[]> {
        return this._http.get(someURL)
            .map(this.extractData)
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }
    private extractData(res: Response) {
        console.log('in extractData and response is ' + res);
        let body = res.json().entity;
        let document = JSON.parse(body).mainprop;
        console.log('data is ' + document);
        return document || { };
    }
    private handleError(error: any) {
        // In a real world app, we might use a remote logging infrastructure
        // We'd also dig deeper into the error to get a better message
        let errMsg = (error.message) ? error.message :
            error.status ? `${error.status} - ${error.statusText}` : 'Server error';
        return Observable.throw(errMsg);
    }
```

Here is my Component that is calling the Service above:

```
 document: SomeComponentInterface[];
    getDocument() {
            this._service.getDocumentService()
                .subscribe(
                document => this.document = document,
                error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
            console.log("document is " + this.document);
        }
```

Here is my .html:

```
<div class="col-xs-12" *ngFor='let resultItem of document'>
        <!-- searchResultItem-->
        <div class="col-xs-6 searchResultItem">
          <div class="col-xs-12 docTitle">
            <p>{{resultItem.fields.prop1}}</p>
          </div>
</div>
```

When i run the code, there is not error but the resultItem displays an array of [object Object]... I think there is an issue with binding the result to SomeComponentInterface. What is it that I am missing? Please help.

thanks for your time.

Comment: What 'literal values' do you want to display?  Because the value that you are printing (the mainprop) is an array of objects, so the output you get is correct.

Comment: hi Steven. thanks for taking time. Sorry I was not so clear about it. I updated my information and basically the issue is with displaying the objects from http call in the html browser. It is not converting into "SomeComponentInterface" which has those fields/properties from the response. The http call is returning the object but not being displayed well.

Comment: update: after an hour, i realized i forgot to map to the correct field. I changed "resultItem" to "resultItem.fields.prop1"... the data is now displaying. thanks.